# How can I add programatically to NSMutableArray and show it on tableviewcells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have textfield,button and `UItableview` in my program.The user enters a text in textfield and when he clicks the button ı want to show his text on `tableviewcell`. He will enter again a text and ı will show him old text in cell-0 and new text is on cell-1. Again and again...
the problem looks like simple.I add an object to `NSMutableArray` when user clicks the send button,but array count always returns 0.Can anyone help me,thx.

Here is my code:

```
int s=0;

-(IBAction)btn_Click:(id)sender{

[array insertObject:txt.text atIndex:s];

s++;

[tableView reloadData];

}

//mytableview delegates

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return  [array count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]init];

    cell.textLabel.text=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
   }
```

Comment: Why are you using insertObject: method instead of addObject:? As you just need to show objects one after another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for sure you forgot to create the array

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

If you dont have any line like this in your code, `array` is `nil`. Many new Objective-C developer struggle with the fact, that it is totally legal to send messages to `nil`.